# jquery inside wordpress ACF custom block can't select element outside of block

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I have an advanced custom fields gutenberg block template like this:

```
<article class="m04x">
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>On this site:</h4>
            <ol id="anchor_list">
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<script>

    (function($) {
        var anchor_list = $('#anchor_list');
        $('.anchor-block').each(function() {
            var heading_text = $(this).html();
            var href = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            var html = '<li class="nav-item"><a class="fontstyle" href="' + href + '">' + heading_text + '</a></li>';
            anchor_list.append(html);
        });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Registered using:

```
function register_on_this_site_block() {
    if ( function_exists( 'acf_register_block' ) ) {
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name'            => 'on-this-site-block',
            'title'           => __( 'On This Site Block', 'wds'),
            'description'     => __( 'Links to parts of current page.', 'wds'),
            'render_template' => get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/blocks/on_this_site.php',
            'category'        => 'layout',
            'icon'            => 'align-center',
            'mode'            => 'preview',
            'keywords'        => array('links'),
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'acf/init', 'register_on_this_site_block' );
```

JQuery can select the '#anchor_list' seemingly because it is in the same template. But when selecting the '.anchor-block' it returns an object with length 0 and the 'each' function does nothing.

How can I access elements outside of this block? Actually it should be mentioned that the '.anchor-block' element resides in another custom ACF block.

Comment: `$('.anchor-block')` is performing a global selector on the entire document, as the document exists at that point in time.  If the selector is returning 0, no element exists matching that selector, at that point in time.

Comment: ACF loads fields via ajax, so you'll need to select the #anchor-block within a callback so it doesn't get called until the fields are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Taplar said, the elements I was selecting did not exist at the time I was trying to select them. I thought my `(function($) { })(jQuery)` function was running after the page has been fully loaded but actually it does not. I changed the code to this and it works:

```
    var $ = (jQuery);
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        var anchor_list = $('#anchor_list');
        $('.anchor-block').each(function() {
            var heading_text = $(this).html();
            var href = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            var html = '<li class="nav-item"><a class="fontstyle" href="' + href + '">' + heading_text + '</a></li>';
            anchor_list.append(html);
        });
    });
```

Although you can see the empty list for a split second before it populates with the `<li>` elements, but thats fine for me.